# Why is this File call coming back as a Syntax Error in UFT?

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am running this in UFT, and have looked at the UFT Help page for guidelines.

```
SystemUtil.Run "note.txt","","C:\Examples\TextFiles","open"
```

Any reason why this is receiving a syntax error?

Comment: The syntax appears to be perfectly fine - when I added it to a `UFT` script it didn't register as a syntax error when I pressed `Ctrl` + `F7` to check it.  What's the syntax error description field say?

Comment: @Dave The description just gives me the line number and the line of code.

Comment: Can you show the code directly before and after this statement?

Comment: @Dave It all came down to the space between .Run and "note.txt". Not entirely sure why, but it works now.